# How to get immediate first larger value when property values is same using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For the array of object `arrobj`, if the id `id` matches with input id `idparam`

how to get the immediate first larger value `cost` object using javascript

Tried

```js
var result = arrobj.find((e, index) => e.id === idparam && arrobj.indexOf(index));
```

example 1

```js
var idparam1 = 22; 
var arrobj1 = [
  {id:11, cost: 4},
  {id:22, cost: 2}
  {id:33, cost: 1},
  {id:44, cost: 5} 
]
```

Expected output:

```js
{id:11, cost: 4}
```

example 2

```js
var idparam2 = 33; 
var arrobj2 = [
  {id:11, cost: 4},
  {id:22, cost: 2},
  {id:33, cost: 1},
  {id:44, cost: 5},
  {id:54, cost: 6} 
]
```

Expected output:

```js
{id:22, cost: 2}
```

Comment: By "immediate" do you mean "previous"?

Comment: @Andy thanks for reply, next value

Comment: Ah. Next greatest cost? What if there are two objects with the same next greatest cost?

Comment: in my scenario there won't be same value since I make it null, I got stuck not sure how to get next first larger value `cost` in javascript.

Comment: `arrobj.indexOf(index)` is searching for a number in a list of objects, and it will always fail, returning a result of `-1`, which is truthy and has no effect whatsoever to the whole expression of `e.id === idparam && arrobj.indexOf(index)`.

Comment: ...idk how you should get {id:11, cost: 2} for example 2, is there a pattern I don't see...? I don't even understand your question...specifying what "immediate first larger value cost object" means would help immensely.

Comment: In example 2, shouldn't it return **{id:11, cost: 4}**??

Comment: @Asphodel he means that if the param for `example 1` is `22` the `cost` value for that object is `2`, the next bigger number is `4`  so the object he should be getting as a result is `{id:11, cost: 4}`

Comment: @imvain2 no, the `cost` value for id `33` is `1` so next cost value is `2`

Comment: @Asphodel@Chris G@imvain, my scenario is when` idparam matches with id in the object, check the cost value, next consecutive will be larger value`

Comment: In Example 1, {id:22, cost: 2} idparam matches with this object, next consecutive cost value is 4. should return {id:11, cost: 4}

Comment: What is confusing, is how the ID and cost don't match in the expected outcome. So in the second example, shouldn't it then be id 22 and cost 2?

Comment: In Example 2,  {id:33, cost: 1}, idparam matches with this object, next consecutive cost value is 2. should return {id:22, cost: 2},

Comment: @imvain2 that was probably a typo from his end

Comment: @imvain2 sorry, I updated the example, yes you are right, typo mistake

Comment: so if you want it simple then: arrObj.findIndex((obj)=> obj.id==idparam) - 1 for index, assuming your array is sorted

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting

```js
function nextLarger(arr, id) {
  const sorted = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost);
  const index = sorted.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  return sorted[index + 1];
}

console.log(
  nextLarger(
    [
      { id: 11, cost: 4 },
      { id: 22, cost: 2 },
      { id: 33, cost: 1 },
      { id: 44, cost: 5 },
    ],
    22
  )
);

console.log(
  nextLarger(
    [
      { id: 11, cost: 4 },
      { id: 22, cost: 2 },
      { id: 33, cost: 1 },
      { id: 44, cost: 5 },
      { id: 44, cost: 6 },
    ],
    11
  )
);
```

Same without sorting

```js
function nextLarger(arr, id) {
  const cost = arr.find((item) => item.id === id).cost;
  let larger = Infinity
  let best = undefined
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item.cost > cost && item.cost < larger) {
      larger = item.cost
      best = item
    }
  }
  return best;
}

console.log(
  nextLarger(
    [
      { id: 11, cost: 4 },
      { id: 22, cost: 2 },
      { id: 33, cost: 1 },
      { id: 44, cost: 5 },
    ],
    22
  )
);

console.log(
  nextLarger(
    [
      { id: 11, cost: 4 },
      { id: 22, cost: 2 },
      { id: 33, cost: 1 },
      { id: 44, cost: 5 },
      { id: 44, cost: 6 },
    ],
    11
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this into a traditional for-loop; and return the previous, if larger.

```js
const findPrevLargest = (arr, id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) {
      return (i > 0 && arr[i - 1].cost > arr[i].cost)
        ? arr[i - 1]
        : arr[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(findPrevLargest([
  { id: 11, cost: 4 },
  { id: 22, cost: 2 },
  { id: 33, cost: 1 },
  { id: 44, cost: 5 } 
], 22)); // { id: 11, cost: 4 }

console.log(findPrevLargest([
  { id: 11, cost: 4 },
  { id: 22, cost: 2 },
  { id: 33, cost: 1 },
  { id: 44, cost: 5 },
  { id: 44, cost: 6 } 
], 33)); // { id: 22, cost: 2 }
```